# SQL, check user constraints

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

First, the table:

```
CLASS CLASS_NAME           PROFESSOR          NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS       COST START_DAT END_DATE  ROO
----- -------------------- ------------------ ------------------ ---------- --------- --------- ---
PC102 Peripherals          Henry Higgins                      12  $1,100.00 11-JAN-13 11-MAY-13 129
PC101 MS OFFICE BASICS     INDIANA JONES                      18  $1,000.00 10-JAN-13 10-MAY-13 127
EE101 Elementary Education Frank McCourt                      22    $900.00 12-JAN-13 12-MAY-13 227
PC123 MS OFFICE ADVANCED   Bill Gates                         10    $800.00 13-JAN-13 13-MAY-13 180
```

**The problem:**

Add a check constraint to number of students to ensure capacity is between 12 and 25 
students.

**What I've tried**

```
ALTER TABLE BW_CLASS
ADD CHECK( NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS > 15  AND
NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS < 25);
```

**What is returned**
    **ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-02293: cannot validate (STUDENT.SYS_C007516) - check constraint violated**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside from Mike W's answer, if you want to check that "capacity is between 12 and 25 students" I'd think you'd use: "NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS BETWEEN 12 AND 25"

Comment: Thanks, Didn't think that. Ill alter it and try again......but is my SQL right? Do I need to use the waor 'CONSTRAINT' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table you're trying to apply the check to already has values that fail the check. Fix the entries in the table that fail, then apply the check.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the number of students in each class is between 12 and 25. update table, where number of students is below 12 increase to > 12. Where it's higher than 25 reduce.